# aerosol optical depth

Tags: remote-sensing

i want to extract aerosol optical depth on land using modis it seems like I need a value from one of these parameters between Corrected_Optical_Depth_Land and Corrected_Optical_Depth_Land_wav2pl  but don't know what one to use can anyone please tell me the difference between these tow or if it better to use another parameter. ?

Answer (score 1):

[image: subdataset]
These are two different products that refer to different wavelengths.

Corrected_Optical_Depth_Land provides information on 0.47, 0.55, and 0.66 µm. This is in the visible range.

Corrected_Optical_Depth_Land_wav2pl provides information on 2.13 µm. This is in the SWIR spectral range.

Depending on your application, either of these products may be the one you need. For most uses, the Corrected_Optical_Depth_Land is the correct one, but since you haven't provided any information on your end-use, it is impossible to say for certain.

Comment: thank you for your help it seems that all the info that i need is within the first one but there is 3 different optic depth in my subdataset witch one should i choose  if there is any different between them

Comment: @khodorsabra You haven't given any details on your application, so it is impossible for me to tell you which is correct. The three subdatasets provide information on the optical thickness at different wavelengths. Depending on your use, you may want a specific one of the three, the maximum, the minimum or the mean.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162697/corrected-optical-depth-3-different-subdataset-in-extract-window if you can help thank you